# Array of programmer defined objects returns duplicates despite different args in the constructor

Tags: c#, .net

I am a Javascript developer trying to learn C# more intensely and am running into a weird issue.

The project is a dotnet web API and is a personal for fun project that is a table top version of bloodborne. I have an origin controller that returns JSON at the endpoint that roughly looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "originName": "Milquetoast",
        "originDescription": "Ordinary, happy upbringing. All attributes average.",
        "originStartingLevels": {
            "vitality": {
                "name": "Vitality",
                "description": "Stat that governs health, increasing it will increase total HP.",
                "startingLevel": 11,
                "level": 0
            },
            "endurance": {
                "name": "Endurance",
                "description": "Stat that governs stamina, increasing it will increase total stamina, allowing for more sprinting, attacks and dodging before running out.",
                "startingLevel": 10,
                "level": 0
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "originName": "Lone Survivor",
        "originDescription": "Lone survivor of lost hamlet. High life essence and vigor.",
        "originStartingLevels": {
            "vitality": {
                "name": "Vitality",
                "description": "Stat that governs health, increasing it will increase total HP.",
                "startingLevel": 11,
                "level": 0
            },
            "endurance": {
                "name": "Endurance",
                "description": "Stat that governs stamina, increasing it will increase total stamina, allowing for more sprinting, attacks and dodging before running out.",
                "startingLevel": 10,
                "level": 0
            }
        }
    }
]
```

The code for the controller looks like this:

```
//code
OriginModel[] Origins =
            {
                new OriginModel(OriginModel.OriginType.Milquetoast),
                new OriginModel(OriginModel.OriginType.LoneSurvivor)
            };
return Origins
```

In the OriginModel there is a class used call PlayerStatModel that takes an origin and sets stats based on the origin:

```
public static int VitalityStartingValue(OriginModel.OriginType origin) =>
            origin switch
            {
                OriginModel.OriginType.Milquetoast => 11,
                OriginModel.OriginType.LoneSurvivor => 14,
                OriginModel.OriginType.TroubledChildhood => 9,
                OriginModel.OriginType.ViolentPast => 12,
                OriginModel.OriginType.Professional => 9,
                OriginModel.OriginType.MilitaryVeteran => 10,
                OriginModel.OriginType.NobleScion => 7,
                OriginModel.OriginType.CruelFate => 10,
                OriginModel.OriginType.WasteOfSkin => 10,
                _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
            };
```

Based on the code, we would expect that if the origin is Milquetoast, the vitality would be set to 11 and if the origin is Lone Survivor, the vitality would be set to 14.

Instead, they are both set to 11. When I add in all 9 of the starting classes, there are three duplicates, before the code appears to start working.

Any ideas why the vitality is 11 and not 14 for the Lone Survivor object response?

******EDIT******
OriginModel looks like this

```
using BloodBorneTableTopGame.Models.PlayerStatsModel;

namespace BloodBorneTableTopGame.Models.OriginModels
{
    public class OriginModel
    {

        public OriginModel(OriginType origin)
        {
            CharacterOrigin = origin;
            _CharacterOrigin = origin;
        }
        public enum OriginType
        {
            Milquetoast,
            LoneSurvivor,
            TroubledChildhood,
            ViolentPast,
            Professional,
            MilitaryVeteran,
            NobleScion,
            CruelFate,
            WasteOfSkin
        }

        public OriginType CharacterOrigin;
        public static OriginType _CharacterOrigin;

        public string OriginName { get { return GetName(CharacterOrigin); } }

        public string OriginDescription { get { return Description(CharacterOrigin); } }
        public string Description(OriginType origin) =>
            origin switch
            {
                OriginType.Milquetoast => "Ordinary, happy upbringing. All attributes average.",
                OriginType.LoneSurvivor => "Lone survivor of lost hamlet. High life essence and vigor.",
                OriginType.TroubledChildhood => "Suffered misfortune in youth. Highly resilient as a result.",
                OriginType.ViolentPast => "Terribly violent past. Rash, but stronger for it.",
                OriginType.Professional => "Born specialist, fit for sleuthing or academia.",
                OriginType.MilitaryVeteran => "Experienced in war. A soldier with strength and skill.",
                OriginType.NobleScion => "Scion to a respectable line with faith in your pedigree.",
                OriginType.CruelFate => "Faced terrible hardships, but now confident in your purpose.",
                OriginType.WasteOfSkin => "You are nothing. Talentless. You shouldn't have been born.",
                _ => "Error: No Origin Type Selected"
            };
        public string GetName(OriginType origin) =>
            origin switch
            {
                OriginType.Milquetoast => "Milquetoast",
                OriginType.LoneSurvivor => "Lone Survivor",
                OriginType.TroubledChildhood => "Troubled Childhood",
                OriginType.ViolentPast => "Violent Past",
                OriginType.Professional => "Professional",
                OriginType.MilitaryVeteran => "Military Veteran",
                OriginType.NobleScion => "Noble Scion",
                OriginType.CruelFate => "Cruel Fate",
                OriginType.WasteOfSkin => "Waste of Skin",
                _ => "Error: No Origin Type Selected"
            };

        private PlayerStatModel _OriginStartingLevels = new PlayerStatModel(_CharacterOrigin);

        public PlayerStatModel OriginStartingLevels { get => _OriginStartingLevels;  }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show `OriginModel` and `OriginModel.OriginType`'s definition.

Comment: The last part of the puzzle I think we're missing now is how the response is generated. It seems likely that your vitality model is a class, and that you're just reusing the same instance of it when you generate the results (i.e. you assign a reference to a single vitality object to many origin objects).

Comment: Issue here is static fields and properties, these are shared between all the objects, last assignment wins. You must have instance fields and properties for those to be per-object.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is related to the fact that the property `_CharacterOrigin` is static and probably shouldn't be. In your `OriginModel` constructor you are essentially assigning the `OriginType` to this static property which results in that static property always containing the last `OriginType` you created.
You then reference this static property when you reference `OriginStartingLevels`, which references `_OriginStartingLevels` which returns a new `PlayerModel` for the last created `OriginModel` - not the `OriginModel` of the instance you are referencing it from.

I believe if you change the code to something like....

```
private PlayerStatModel _OriginStartingLevels = null;

public PlayerStatModel OriginStartingLevels {
  get
  {
    if (_OriginStartingLevels == null)
      _OriginStartingLevels = new PlayerStatModel(CharacterOrigin);
    return _OriginStartingLevels;
   }
}
```

...it will do what you want and you can then remove the static `_CharacterOrigin` property from your class.

Comment: I agree it is probably due to static property, but I cant add a non static property as an argument. I supspect at this point more than anything that the architecture ofthe objects is the main problem, and major refactoring is in order